# the energy relations in oceanography description

Tags: oceanography

I'm reading the following [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2153-3490.1967.tb01462.x/pdf) and do not entirely understand a point that the author is trying to make. In page 99 (2 of article) the author refers to the following equation:

$$ Q^{*} = \beta S^{*}e^{-\beta z} + 2B^{*} \delta \left(z\right) $$

and in the following paragraph he states that

"The first term on the right represents the convergence of the penetrating component S^{*} of solar radiation"

My immediate question is does "first term" refer to the $2B^{*}\delta\left(z\right)$ or does it refer to "2B"? i.e. does rhs mean rhs of the equal sign or what?

In addition, can anyone explain, in layman's terms, what this equation is referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first term on the right is  $\beta S^{*}e^{-\beta z}$

This means that the amount of light penertrating into the ocean decreases exponentially with depth $z$.

The second term on the right is $2B^{*} \delta \left(z\right)$

This takes into account heat transfer processes taking place only at the surface, such as evaportion.

Comment: why is there an additional beta term at the start. Beer's law should be Se-beta z, right?

Comment: because the amount of heating is the rate if change (derivative) of the amount of light penetrating to the depth. In other words, decrease in the amount of light, results in heat being absorbed, so it is necessary to take the derivative of the exponential function.